# Exporting a map containing a struct as value to csv with Golang

Tags: dictionary, go, struct, export-to-csv

I have a map which has a struct as value, as below:

```
type Record struct {
    ID   int
    Type string
    Year string
}

m := make(map[int]Record)
```

Once I populate this map with some records, I'm trying to export them as a csv with:

```
file, err := os.Create("export.csv")
checkError("Error:", err)
defer file.Close()
writer := csv.NewWriter(file)
defer writer.Flush()

for key, value := range m {
    r := make([]string, 0, 1+len(value))
    r = append(r, key)
    r = append(r, value)
}
writer.Flush()
```

I'm getting the error `invalid argument value (type Record) for len`. How should I handle the struct here to? Do I have to convert it to string somehow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few issues here:

1. `writer.Write` takes an argument of type `[]string` so trying to append anything other than a string to `r` (which I assume is a shorthand representation of *record*) will not work.
2. You cannot get the length of a struct. See the [builtin](https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#len) documentation for more info about the types you can pass in to `len`.

I've made a few modifications to your code:

- provide headers for the csv for ease of readability
- update `r` to accept capacity of `len(headers)`, equals 4- I wasn't sure what you wanted the capacity to be but you can easily update this to be (probably 3, not 4).
- convert ID field to string in order to add to `[]string` for `writer.Write`

Test [here](https://play.golang.org/p/ZPrPqFZ2sbN) in Go Playground.

*Example:*

```
type Record struct {
    ID   int
    Type string
    Year string
}

m := make(map[int]Record)

// populate this map with some records

file, err := os.Create("export.csv")
checkError("Error:", err)
defer file.Close()
writer := csv.NewWriter(file)
defer writer.Flush()

// define column headers
headers := []string{
    "id",
    "type",
    "year",
}

// write column headers
writer.Write(headers)

var idString string

for key := range m {

    r := make([]string, 0, 1+len(headers)) // capacity of 4, 1 + the number of properties your struct has & the number of column headers you are passing

    // convert the Record.ID to a string in order to pass into []string
    idString = strconv.Itoa(m[key].ID)

    r = append(
        r,
        idString,
        m[key].Type,
        m[key].Year,
    )

    writer.Write(r)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the very detailed and friendly answer - your assumption was correct about the length of the `r` variable.

Answer (score 1):

Your code has several problems. Try something like this:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/csv"
    "os"
    "strconv"
)

func main() {
    type Record struct {
        ID   int
        Type string
        Year string
    }

    m := make(map[int]Record)
    r := Record{ID: 1, Type: "A", Year: "2019"}
    m[r.ID] = r

    f, err := os.Create("export.csv")
    if err != nil {
        // handle error
    }
    defer f.Close()
    w := csv.NewWriter(f)
    defer w.Flush()

    for _, v := range m {
        r := make([]string, 0, 3)
        r = append(r, strconv.Itoa(v.ID))
        r = append(r, v.Type)
        r = append(r, v.Year)
        err := w.Write(r)
        if err != nil {
            // handle error
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
$ go run export.go
$ cat export.csv
1,A,2019
$
```

Answer (score -1):

You are trying to apply `len()` on the struct instead of the map
Try the following:

```
file, err := os.Create("export.csv")
checkError("Error:", err)
defer file.Close()
writer := csv.NewWriter(file)
defer writer.Flush()

r := make([]string, 0, 1+len(m))
for key, value := range m {
    r = append(r, key)
    r = append(r, value)
}
writer.Flush()
```